# A compound that reacts with ethyl magnesium bromide and also decolorizes bromine water

Tags: organic-chemistry, grignard-reagent

Which of the following compounds reacts with ethyl magnesium bromide and also
decolorizes bromine water solution:

[image]

Is the answer only option (c)?

Comment: Can you explain what made you think so?

Comment: @RahulVerma The double bond present outside the ring will decolorize bromine water and the -OH becomes -OMgBr and $C_2H_6$ is formed. However, in option (d), the nitrile also reacts with Grignard to give an imine and eventually a ketone and the ring (which isn't benzene) has double bonds but I'm not sure if those double bonds can decolorize bromine water.

Comment: Good analysis. I bet that d) is missing a double bond.

Comment: Oh, my bad. I didn't noticed (d) wasn't benzene deriv.